# Given $f(1)=10,f(2)=20,f(3)=30$ find $f(12)+f(-8)$ for a 4-th degree monic polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials

If $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.
Given $f(1)=10,f(2)=20,f(3)=30$ find $f(12)+f(-8)$.
This problem has troubled me a lot.The more I try to solve it,it becomes lengthier.

My problem is that there are four unknowns and only three equations.

Please help me.

Answer (score 21):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - 10x$, we have 
$$g(1) = g(2) = g(3) = 0\quad\implies\quad (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \;\;\text{ divides }\;\;g(x)$$
As a result, $f(x)$ has the form

$$f(x) = 10x + (x-t)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$
for suitably chosen constant $t$. Notice 
$$\begin{align}
(12-1)(12-2)(12-3) &= 990\\
(-8-2)(-8-1)(-8-3) &= -990
\end{align}$$
we have
$$\begin{align}
f(12) + f(-8) 
&= 10(12 - 8) + 990(12-t) - 990(-8-t)\\
&= 40 + 990 \times 20 = 19840
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very interesting solution.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting solution, but unfortunately your answer is not the same as mine... Who is correct?

Comment: Even I am wondering. :|

Comment: @wythagoras As a habit, I have verified my answer by independent mean before posting it. (this time by a CAS).

Comment: I think someone else has similar answer.

Comment: Gr8 I admire your thinking capacity.

Answer (score 5):

We know that

$$1+a+b+c+d=10$$
$$16+8a+4b+2c+d=20$$
$$81+27a+9b+3c+d=30$$

And we want to know

$$f(12)+f(-8)=24832+1216a+208b+4c+2d$$

Knowing that we can add the 24,832 later, it is sufficient to know

$$608a+104b+2c+d$$

---

We want $z$ times the first equation, $y$ times the second  and $x$ times the third. This gives the equations, ignoring the number of $a$s:

$$x+y+z=1$$

$$3x+2y+z=2$$

$$9x+4y+z=104$$

First two equations give $2x+y=1$, first and second gives $8x+3y=103$, so $2x=100$ and $x=50$. This gives $y=-99$ and $z=50$.

You know why I am happy? Because it turns out that $50\cdot 27-99\cdot8+50\cdot1=608$.

---

So 50 times the first equation plus -99 times the second plus 50 times the third gives $608a+104b+2c+d-2516=20$, thus $24832+1216a+208b+4c+2d=19840$

Comment: Last statement misses constant term $50f(1) -99f(2) + 50f(3) = 2516 + 608 a + 104 b + 2c +d$. You've dropped that term from $f(x)$

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The fact that there are three equiations for four unknowns states that the solution will have one unconstrained unknown. Since you're asked for a concrete answer, the $f(12) + f(-8)$ is a specially crafted expression that doesn't depend that particular unconstrained unknown.

Let's simplifiy things by introducing $y = x - 2$. Let $g(y)$ be $f(x)$ for this new variable: 
$$
g(y) = f(y + 2) = (y + 2)^4 + a (y+2)^3 + \dots = 
y^4 + A y^3 + B y^2 + C y + D.
$$
$g(y)$ has similar constraints, 
$$
g(-1) = f(1) = 10\\
g(0) = f(2) = 20\\
g(1) = f(3) = 30
$$
and we're asked about $f(12) + f(-8) = g(10) + g(-10)$. Note the symmetry in constraints and the value we are interesting in.
Now, 
$$
40 = g(-1) + g(1) = 2\cdot 1^4 + 2B\cdot 1^2 + 2D = 2 + 2B + 2D\\
40 = 2g(0) = g(0) + g(-0) = 2\cdot 0^4 + 2B\cdot 0^2 + 2D = 2D\\
g(10) + g(-10) = 2\cdot 10^4 + 2B\cdot 10^2 + 2D = 20000 - 200 + 40 = 19840
$$

Comment: Again another nice substitution.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Solve the system
$$1+a+b+c+d=10$$
$$16+8a+4b+2c+d=20$$
$$81+27a+9b+3c+d=30$$

Comment: That's the problem with three equations and four variables it is impossible to solve this system.

Comment: Maybe you don't need all of them at all. There will probably be a condition in your answer that will allow you to replace some condition by other. That the dependency of answer decreases. I'd prefer to represent this conditions in reduced row echelon form.

Comment: you can solve this system

Comment: @MayankJha: if you add the expansion of $f(12)+f(-8)=N$ to these three lines and consider only the coefficients of $a,b,c,d$ you'll get a degenerate matrix (det$=0$) so that the missing number $N$ will be imposed by the three other lines.